# read from file inside jar in web application

Tags: servlets, jar

I've got a stand alone application that I exported as JAR file to include it in a web application running on Tomcat.

The stand alone app reads from a file which is inside the package "config", through this line:

```
configFileName = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("config/indexer.cfg").getPath();
```

Unfortunately this causes an exception in the web app:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.23\IRSimWebApp\WEB-INF\lib\IR_Sim.jar!\config\indexer.cfg (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

I noticed that there's an exclamation mark in the file path. Could this cause the error? How did it get there?

Comment: I guess, what you are doing is correct. The exlclamation means it is inside the JAR.

Comment: That line can impossibly cause the given exception. Aren't you incorrectly doing `new FileInputStream(configFileName)` further down in the code? That would match the exception.

Comment: Yeah, It's caused by a new FileInputStream later in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you would be better served by getting the resource as an `InputStream`:

```
InputStream in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config/indexer.cfg");
if (in != null) {
    BufferedInputStream buff = new BufferedInputStream(in);
    // process buff to get contents of file
    buff.close();
}
```

No exception handling above, obviously, but you should get the idea...